# Xubuntu 17.10 (and later): cannot change xfce4-terminal keyboard shortcuts

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, xfce, xfce4-terminal

I've just installed xubuntu 17.10 and cannot change xfce4-terminal keyboard shortcuts. I tried enabling editable accelerators (according to http://docs.xfce.org/faq), running:

***Appearance -> Settings -> Menus and Buttons -> Enable editable accelerators: Tick***

but when I hover the mouse over any menu item and press any key combination, nothing happens; I can see all shortcuts are greyed out, indicating that they can't be changed. I closed/reopened xfce4-terminal, and also logged out/in from the xfce session, to no avail, still can't change the shortcuts.

Don't know what changed in xfce because I remember being able to do this in past versions. I'm running fresh xubuntu 17.10, so xfce is version 4.12.3 and xfce4-terminal is 0.8.6-0ubuntu1.

Would anybody know how to change them ?

**EDIT**: I've just discovered that they can be changed editing:

***~/.config/xfce4/terminal/accels.scm***

Remove the leading **;** from the menu entry and edit the shortcut. xfce4-terminal has to be closed/reopened for the new shortcuts to take effect. Not sure if this is the standard way of doing it, but at least it works.

**EDIT 2**: Found a good explanation about it [here](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/37970721-editable-accelerators-no-more-working-in-xfce4-terminal-after-gtk-3-migration)

Comment: The `~/.config/xfce4/terminal/accels.scm` file doesn't seem to have any effect for me (xfce4-terminal 0.8.3 on MXLinux 17)

Comment: So place you findings as an answer.

Comment: Thanks very much for documenting this.  These shortcuts have definitely been a moving target over the years.  I'm not sure where the accelerators went, but just as I got used to those they decided to keep us on our toes :P

I remember when they used to be simple, menu-driven deal, but yeah, not the worst thing to have this direct in a config file.  I'm about to throw it into ansible now so I don't forget.  Cheers!

Comment: Oh, also just want to note that this identical across *nixes I think.  That config file mentioned in OP existed for me and I'm on FreeBSD 11.1, xfce 4.12, and 0.8.7.3 of xfce4-terminal.  This worked like a charm for me.  But yeah, be sure to exit ALL open xfce terminal windows after updating config

Comment: @ChristopherKuttruff, I get the impression it's a generic GTK method for setting accelerators, even though the specific filename may differ. For instance, I see that quodlibet uses *~/.config/quodlibet/accels*, geeqie uses *~/.config/geeqie/accels*, Thunar uses *~/.config/Thunar/accels.scm*.

Comment: For sure.  I like the consistency there and definitely gonna start getting these configs into version control.  Would much rather have Scheme as an extension tool than some GUI menu :)  Actually had no idea xfce was using scheme for extension stuff... super cool!

Answer (score 2):

As the solution was present in the question and in comments (along with contradictory statements) I will post an answer to make it more clear.

As said under Xfce bug report [#12861 — "editable accelerators no more working in xfce4-terminal after GTK+3 migration"](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12861#c2):

> gtk3 does not support editable accelerators. Since xfce4-terminal is a
>   gtk3 app, this feature isn't available anymore...

That affects all later Xubuntu versions, not just 17.10.

> accelerators can be changed via ~/.config/xfce4/terminal/accels.scm

While editing that file, as the OP said in the question, you have to `remove the lead` (the `;` part at the beginning of the line); example for Ctrl-C for copy and Ctrl-V for paste:

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/paste" "<Primary>v")
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/copy" "<Primary>c")
```